# Get specific uuid object in view from model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have django app in which user can upload files in course with 3 editable fields.

*models.py*

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails', null=False, default='default.jpg')
    videofile = models.FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator], upload_to='videos')
    
    def path(self):
        return self.url
```

I have view to display those the thumbnails of all courses and when user click on thumbnail it redirects him to course detail page.

*urls.py*

```
path('course/<uuid:course_id>/', views.course_detail, name='course-detail')
```

> **So my question is how can I get information about fields of model Course in my html file to display them.**

*views.py*

```
def course_detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
    course = models.Course.objects.get()
    context = {
        'course': course,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/info_course_view.html', context)
```

Without uuid  i would just write *pk=pk* in brackets but since i use uuid i don't know how to make it work.

*template*

```
<div class="container">
    {{ course.title }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to modify your views and urls file as follows:

urls.py:

```
path('course/<str:course_id>/', views.course_detail, name='course-detail')
```

views.py:

```
def course_detail(request, course_id):
    course = models.Course.objects.get(course_id=course_id)
    context = {
        'course': course,
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/info_course_view.html', context)
```

template file:

```
<div class="container">
{{ course.title }}
</div>
```

In fact, the main issue is that you didn't put the course_id inside the course argument.